# How to display months in the correct sequence?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, apexcharts

How to get months like in the picture? Now I see - feb20

[image]

```
const chartOptions = {
        options: {
            chart: {
                id: "basic-bar"
            },
            xaxis: {
                labels: {
                    formatter: function(value, timestamp, index) {
                        return moment(new Date()).format("MMM YYYY")
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [
            {
                name: "Доход",
                data: [onSumArr() !== undefined ? onSumArr() : 0]
            }
        ]
    };
```

Now I do like this, and it does not work.

Comment: Try looking at this example, if you are using HighCharts library :) https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-labels/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem arises here

```
return moment(new Date()).format("MMM YYYY")
```

Date() initializes as the current date month, now February. You need to set the month of the date with `date.setMonth([0-11])`. `timestamp` or `index` in the anonymous function parameters could provide that.

I'm not an expert in apexCharts, but you could replace your formatter with this:

```
formatter: function(value, timestamp, index) {
    var startDate = moment(new Date('2019-12-01T00:00:00'));
    startDate.add(index, 'months');
    return moment(startDate).format("MMM YYYY")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `xaxis.labels.formatter` function to

```js
formatter: function(val, timestamp) {
  return moment(new Date(timestamp)).format("MMM YYYY")
}
```

Comment: Create a codepen demo so I can see what your full code is.

Comment: Here is your update codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-60085554-k9ywg

Comment: And what will happen in April?